# Hide a Button in a ButtonBar

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex

I was wondering if there is any way you hide a particular button in a ButtonBar. According to this answer (and the link provided in the second answer) [Disable individual buttons in a buttonbar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1005145/disable-individual-buttons-in-a-buttonbar) I need to use the getChildAt method of the ButtonBar, but when I do that I get the custom skin object and not the Button object. I was wondering how I could get access to the Button object.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you using the MX ButtonBar or the Spark ButtonBar?  IF the Spark, the answer you linked to doesn't quote apply.  The concept is the same, though.  Find the button and toggle its visibility.  Or, possibly, remove that button from the ButtonBar's dataProvider without having to toggle individual visibility on a button.

Comment: Oh I didn't consider that, you're right, it's Spark. I need to toggle visibility as removing the button messes up the index which a bunch of other components rely on (it's pretty tightly coupled :( )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Under the assumption that all buttons in your button bar will be rendered at the same time and you won't need scrollbars...

With a Spark [ButtonBar](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/spark/components/ButtonBar.html#SkinPartSummary), you can access the skin part directly to get access to a button.  Conceptually something like this:

```
var button : Button = mySparkButtonBarInstance.dataGroup.getElementAt(SomeIndex);
button.visible = false; // or true
button.includeInLayout = false;  // or true
```

This won't work if your ButtonBar can make use of Virtual Layouts and requires scrolling.

---

Edit: Here is working code demonstrating this technique:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:WindowedApplication xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
                       xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
                       xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx">

    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import mx.core.IVisualElement;
            protected function button1_clickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
            {
                trace(buttonBar.dataGroup.getElementAt(0));
                var button :IVisualElement = buttonBar.dataGroup.getElementAt(0);
                button.visible = false; // or true
                button.includeInLayout = false;  // or true         }
            }
        ]]>
    </fx:Script>

    <fx:Declarations>
        <!-- Place non-visual elements (e.g., services, value objects) here -->
    </fx:Declarations>

    <s:layout>
        <s:VerticalLayout paddingLeft="20" paddingTop="20"/>
    </s:layout>

    <s:ButtonBar id="buttonBar">  
        <mx:ArrayCollection>
            <fx:String>Flash</fx:String> 
            <fx:String>Director</fx:String> 
            <fx:String>Dreamweaver</fx:String> 
            <fx:String>ColdFusion</fx:String> 
        </mx:ArrayCollection>
    </s:ButtonBar>

    <s:Button label="Remove" click="button1_clickHandler(event)" />

</s:WindowedApplication>
```

Comment: I tested around this today and run into some problems: Any ideas why .dataGroup.getElementAt(SomeIndex) always seems to return null even when numElements (and getItemIndicesInView) returns the correct amount? Removing the element from the dataProvider works but changing .visible or pretty much anything else didn't seem to do anything.

Comment: If I had to guess it is a conversion issue.  Did you try casting it as a Button?  `mySparkButtonBarInstance.dataGroup.getElementAt(SomeIndex) as Button`

Comment: Yes. Always null. The dataProvider was a an ArrayCollection that I added the buttons with `for (var i:int=0; i < 10; i++){ var button:Button = new Button(); button.label = "btn"+i.toString(); ac.addItem(button);}` if that makes any difference. (Sorry if there are some typos, I am not on that PC right now)

Comment: I added a full working sample demonstrating this approach. Basically, the getElementAt() returns a ButtonSkin; not a Button so the conversion was going to null.

Comment: Okay, that explains it. +1 from me

Comment: Thanks a bunch for your reply :) I'm still getting a button skin (don't have access to the code now so can't give you more detailed info, but will post an update tomorrow)